How to run a function when an offscreened Unity game is closed?
I'm working on a Unity project for Android, and I need to trigger a function when the game app is closed or is closed while is in the background.
I tried using OnApplicationQuit() in the MonoBehaviour component which has the function I need to run, but it doesn't seem to trigger when the app goes into the background on Android.
I also tried using OnApplicationPause(bool isPaused), but it does not handles all the cases where the app is truly "closed", only when is just minimized.
Any suggestions or ideas on how I could solve this would be greatly appreciated!

This question is similar to: How to get event When Apps kill from Task manager in Android?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@shingo we had this issue on HoloLens as well where killing the task via Task Manager is basically the standard ^^ In our case we solved this using a class with finalizer which triggered the cleanup (e.g. killing processes and closing file streams etc) .. could this also work here? I believe the duplicate is more in general for getting notified from external when an app is closed on android .. in this case OP has control about what is implemented internal of the app itself

The alternative would be to run a background demon/service that connects to your actual app - if for any reason your app suddenly disappears from the running tasks then this background service triggers the cleanup and kills itself .. again more experience on UWP and standalone .. this might be completely different on Android

Do you mean a C# class finalizer? Will finalizers really run before a process is killed? I doubt this. Is it possible that processes and files are closed because the main process is killed? Or this is a special case on HoloLens.

So without this on HL the files remained in a lock state as well as background processes kept running - with the finalizer they got killed along. As said no clue how this is on Android but we had a lot of pain with this kind of task manager approaches nowadays ^^
